# TinyMCE-- When clicked on upload files button "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" error occures

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, tinymce

[Plese click on this link to open error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G64fF.png)

[image]

When i click on upload file button in TinyMCE this error occurs "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: What error? And post your code.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette https://www.screencast.com/t/QGqVgLev 
then this is the error page https://i.stack.imgur.com/G64fF.png

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a virtual mapping to your IIS' site. Name it `jakarta` and let it point to the folder containing the `isapi_redirect.dll`, usually that's `X:\ColdFusionXXXX\config\wsconfig\1` (change the path's drive letter and ColdFusion version).

Alternatively you can run the webserver configuration wizard located at: `X:\ColdFusionXXXX\cfusion\runtime\bin\wsconfig.exe`
It's a GUI with a few options to setup connectors for your IIS.